# how to get text to disappear after few seconds

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Hi guys I am building my game right now and trying to get some text to disappear after a few seconds. I am using Phaser and I am not to sure how to do this.

Currently I have:

```
Asteroid.time.events.remove(Phaser.Timer.SECOND - 3, this.startInstructions3, this);
```

My text appears on the page fine:

```
if (!this.rockmodel.countLiving()) {
    Asteroid.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 3, this.levelIncrease, this);
    var startInstructions3 = 'NEXT LEVEL! ';
    this.gametext3 = Asteroid.add.text(Asteroid.world.centerX, Asteroid.world.centerY, startInstructions3, lifefont3.thefont3);
    this.gametext3.align = 'center';
    this.gametext3.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

Then when I go back to my `levelIncrease` function i have :

```
if (this.rockcount < rocksincoming.max) {
        this.rockcount += rocksincoming.astup;  
}
Asteroid.time.events.remove(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 3, this.startInstructions3, this);
    this.randomrock();
},
endofgame: function () {
    Asteroid.state.start(gameobjectstouse.menu);
},
```

My question is, is it like -3 or is there a set thing you can do in Phaser like duration or something like that? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually [an official example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/time/basic-timed-event) that covers this scenario for you.

Your `Asteroid.time.events.remove()` would actually remove an event, not add a removal event. For example, if you had an event that looped and wanted to remove that event, you would use `time.events.remove`.

So you want to add an event that triggers after three seconds, so something like the following, instead of your `Asteroid.time.events.remove` line:

```
Asteroid.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND - 3, this.nameOfFunctionToHideText, this);
```

Where `nameOfFunctionToHideText` (or whatever new function you create) would be the one that would remove the text.